# Erro de tradução: "Seu answer não pode ser criado"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Experimentem responder uma questão no meta com menos de 30 caracteres. Aparecerá a mensagem:

> Seu answer não pode ser enviado.

Sugestões?

Comment: Na verdade a mensagem que mostra é "Seu answer não pôde ser **enviado**. Verifique os erros acima.". Talvez você devesse atualizar sua pergunta para não induzir respostas como a do @aldison e talvez até ajudar o moderador que vai corrigir o erro a encontrar a msg no sistema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acho que a tradução literal do original em inglês cabe bem:

> Sua resposta não pôde ser enviada. Verifique os erros acima.

Comment: Em tempo: Como submeter uma solicitação de correção de tradução? Existe alguma ferramenta disponível para que um usuário possa contribuir com a localização?

Comment: Basta continuar postando aqui no meta. A indicação é usar a tag `internacionalização` quando todo ou parte do conteúdo não foi traduzido (i.e. pode envolver a equipe de desenvolvimento), e a tag `localização` quando o conteúdo estiver em português mas a tradução não estiver boa. A tag `tradução` pode (deve?) vir junto. A equipe do SE acompanha essas tags, de acordo com suas responsabilidades, de modo que quem pode fazer alguma coisa já está devidamente notificado através dessa pergunta e suas respostas.

Answer (score 2):

Acertei um monte de strings de erro, que dependiam de um esquema de criação que não dava muito certo ao traduzir.

Vai pro ar no próximo build.

Answer (score 1):

Gostei da tradução de @OnoSendai, porém estamos distanciando do original.

então demostro uma outra opção:

> Sua resposta não pode ser criada.